# Not able to extract a number from a text file

Tags: perl

I have a text file which has the information of the number of tests that were run, passed and failed.

Also it contains information on which of the tests failed.

I want to extract the total number of the tests that were run and failed.

Below is the sample of the log file:

```
file_1 has difference
file_2 has difference
file_3 has difference
file_4 has difference
file_5 has difference
file_6 has difference
file_7 has difference
file_8 has difference
events has difference
QShrink has difference
Total tests run = 10
Total tests passed = 0
Total tests failed = 10
```

I tried to capture it like this, but didn't work:

```perl
if ( $_=~/^# run =/ || $_=~/^# failed =/ ) {
    print $_;
    my $entry = <FILE>;
    print $entry;
}
```

My objective is that I should be able to fetch only the corresponding numbers and not the entire string.

Comment: What are the hash symbols `#` for in your regex patterns? There are no hashes in the data, so `^#` won't match anything. You also appear to be fetching the line *after* the one that matched and printing that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should put the entire line into the pattern and discern based on he last word before the `=`. That makes it flexible, because you don't need to care if all of the lines are present.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use Data::Dumper;

my %stats;
while (<DATA>) {
    if ( m/^Total tests ([a-z]+) = (\d+)/ ) {
        $stats{$1} = $2;
    }
}

print Dumper \%stats;

__DATA__
file_1 has difference
file_2 has difference
file_3 has difference
file_4 has difference
file_5 has difference
file_6 has difference
file_7 has difference
file_8 has difference
events has difference
QShrink has difference
Total tests run = 10
Total tests passed = 0
Total tests failed = 10
```

This solution uses a hash to store the matches.

```
$VAR1 = {
          'failed' => '10',
          'run' => '10',
          'passed' => '0'
        };
```

---

Let's take a look at what you did.

> ```
> if($_=~/^# run =/ || $_=~/^# failed =/)
>                 {
>                     print $_;
>                     my$entry=<FILE>;
>                     print $entry;
>                 }
> ```

This code assumes there is something in `$_`. Maybe you already opened the file and are reading it.

```
while (<DATA>) {
    if ($_ =~ /.../) {
```

So you are saying that if the current line matches the beginning of the string, a `#`, a space, the word *run*, a space and an `=` (or the same with *failed*, it should print the full line, then assign the next line to  a lexical variable that only exists within that block, and print it.

This pattern does not match your input, so the block will never be executed. If it would be, you'd pull away another line of the input for every line that matches.

All of that is not what you want and does not get you anywhere near the numbers.

Comment: It's working. Thanks for your help.
But I am stuck as it returns the data in this format:
$VAR1 = {
          'failed' => '10',
          'run' => '10',
          'passed' => '0'
        };

So, how can I separate the value for the failed field.

Comment: The stats go into a hash called `%stats`. So the "failed" number is in `$stats{failed}` (similarly for "run" and "passed").

Comment: To be honest, if you couldn't work that out for yourself by reading the code, then you should really take the time to read a good [introduction to Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018452.do).

Comment: @Dave : Thanks for your suggestion. I am new to perl. I will go through that book.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_=~/Total tests run = ([0-9]+)/)
         {
              print "Total tests run :$1\n";
         }
```

In the above code the numbers that you want are captured in perls default variable $1 as they are placed in braces. Similarly you can do for failed number of tests.

Comment: That looks rather over-complicated. Why copy `$_` to `$in`? Why copy `$1` to `$count`? Surely it's just `print "Total tests run: $1" if /Total tests run = ([0-9]+)/`

Comment: For a newbie that might not be the best approach.

Comment: Perhaps not. But neither is your unnecessary copying of variables :-)

Comment: It's your answer, of course, so you should have whatever code you want in it. But matching the string twice seems inefficient. Why not combine them into one: `if (/Total tests run = ([0-9]+)/) { print "Total tests run :$1\n"; }`.

Comment: @DaveCross its my answer, but your suggestion :)